# mailto Link Not Working For All Users

Tags: php, wordpress, email, hyperlink, mailto

I am trying to create a button that would allow users to easily send an email and share specific content via email. This works for me, but it doesn't work on my clients machine. I have a feeling it's because a default mail program is not set in his browser, but setting the default program for every user that wants to use this feature defeats the purpose. Is there a way to bypass this in the html? Is there and if/else statement that could be used in case there is no default program?

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=<?php the_title(); ?>&amp;body=<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Send this article to a friend!">SHARE THIS</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `setting the default program for every user that wants to use this feature defeats the purpose.` yes, this is how mailto works, you need to configure mail program on every users computer, actually this is why nobody uses it

Comment: so plan b, and what most sites would do, a form on the website which does the emailing